# Printing nested dictionary loop YYYYMMDD

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help, newbie here.  I want to loop through the days of the month and for each day, print the date in YYYYMMDD format, eg. 20150203 for the third day of February, 2015.

```
initial_values = {'year': 2015}

calendar_5 = {initial_values['year']: {"01": 31, "02": 28}}

for day in range(calendar_5[initial_values['year']]["02"]):
    for year in calendar_5:
        for month, day in calendar_5.items():
            print(calendar_5[initial_values[month]][day])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider re-structuring your dictionary, your data structure has redundant data and does not support multiple days per month. The main dictionary may have years as keys like this:

- The dictionary is like `year: month_dict`
- Each `month_dict` has months as keys and list of month days as values.

So for example, a dictionary for what you need may be like:

```py
my_dict = {
    '2019': {
        '1': [2, 14, 30], # January
        '5': [5, 11, 13]  # May
    }
    '2020': {
        '12': [9] # December
    }
}
```

Being that way, it is really easy to print it:

```py
for year, month_dict in my_dict.items():
    for month, list_days in month_dict.items():
        for day in list_days:
            print('{}{}{}'.format(year, month, day)
```

Comment: You don't need to create own dictionary. Python has build-in library for calendar operations https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html.

Comment: Sure! But but we don 't know if he might be getting the data from a text file or other source, so I wanted to give the answer so it is more flexible. But ye, that's also true.

Comment: I am getting it from a text file - and I know about the calendar library but I'm learning so I wanted to do it myself.  Thanks so much for your help @Cblopez! it is flexible and I think it will really help :)